# Shell: Find a keyword in a file and get the content of the following lines

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to write a shell script which can find a specific word and get the contents of the following lines.

For example I have a file:

```
...[not interested info]...
Keyword: YES
wanted line 1
wanted line 2
wanted line 3
...[not interested info]...
```

I would like to search the keyword 'YES' and got the following 3 lines (assuming the count of lines following is fixed, i.e. 3 in this case):

```
wanted line 1
wanted line 2
wanted line 3
```

I know how to use grep to get the line of the keyword, but not how to get the following lines.

Comment: is the number of following lines fixed?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Yes, let's say it is always 3 lines after the keywod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
grep -A 3 YES
```

which prints 3 lines of trailing context (`-A 3`) after a `YES`.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking something along the lines of:

```
while read line
do
  if [ "" != `grep YES $line` ]; then
    echo read line
    echo read line
    echo read line
  fi
done
```

It's hacky but I am not aware of any more elegant way of doing this. In essence this is just about reading the file line by line and checking for the grep output on each line rather than letting grep go through the whole file by itself.